# How to show all checkboxes in recyclerview?

Tags: android, kotlin, checkbox, android-recyclerview, adapter

I want to display all the checkboxes by long press, but only one is displayed
There is a part of my adapter

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHoldder, position: Int) {
    holder.textView?.text = lstWords[position].engWord
    holder.textView2?.text = lstWords[position].transWord
    holder.textView3?.text = lstWords[position].rusWord
    holder.checkBox?.setOnCheckedChangeListener(object : CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {
        override fun onCheckedChanged(buttonView: CompoundButton?, isChecked: Boolean) {
            val word = Words(
                lstWords[position].idWord!!,
                lstWords[position].engWord!!,
                lstWords[position].transWord!!,
                lstWords[position].rusWord!!,
                lstWords[position].check!!
            )
            if (holder.checkBox?.isChecked!!){
                words.add(word.idWord.toString())
                Log.d("MYTAG", "$words")
            }
            if (!holder.checkBox?.isChecked!!){
                words.remove(word.idWord.toString())
                Log.d("MYTAG", "$words")
            }
        }
    })
    holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener {
        holder.checkBox?.visibility = CheckBox.VISIBLE
        true
    }
}
```

How to change all checkboxes?

Comment: Do your ViewHolder's text views and check boxes really need to be nullable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a property in the adapter class that determines if check boxes should be shown. Call `notifyDataSetChanged()` to force all item views to be rebound, so it will have a chance to modify each of them.

```
private var shouldShowCheckBoxes = false

//...

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHoldder, position: Int) {
    //...
    holder.checkBox?.visiblility = if (shouldShowCheckBoxes) View.VISIBLE else View.INVISIBLE
    holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener {
        shouldShowCheckBoxes = true
        notifyDataSetChanged()
        true
    }
}
```